# Only parsing outer element

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am writing a scraper with Nokogiri, and I want to scrape a large HTML file.

Currently, I am scraping a large table; here is a small fragment:

```
<table id="rptBidTypes__ctl0_dgResults">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">S24327</td>

      <td>
        Airfield Lighting

        <div>
          <div>
          <table cellpadding="5px" border="2" cellspacing="1px" width="100%" bgcolor=
          "black">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="white">Abstract:<br />
                This project is for the purchase and delivery, of various airfield
                lighting, for a period of 36 months, with two optional 1 year renewals,
                in accordance with the specifications, terms and conditions specified in
                the solicitation.</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the Ruby code I am using to scrape:

```
document = doc.search("table#rptBidTypes__ctl0_dgResults tr")
  document[1..-1].each do |v|
   cells = v.search 'td'
   if cells.inner_html.length > 0

     data = {
       number: cells[0].text,

     }
    end
    ScraperWiki::save_sqlite(['number'], data)
  end
```

Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I only want to extract `S24327`, but I am getting the content of every table cell. How do I only extract the content of the first `td`?

Keep in mind that under this table, there are many table rows following the same format.

Comment: BTW, I would rename the variable 'document' to 'rows'.

Comment: 'rows' is better, but 'trs' is most precise.

Comment: Do you want the list of all such codes in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, `table tr` means `tr` anywhere underneath the table, including nested tables. But `table > tr` means the `tr` must be a direct child of the `table`.

Also, it appears you only want the cell values, so you don't need to iterate. This will give you all such cells (the first in each row):

```
doc.search("table#rptBidTypes__ctl0_dgResults > tr > td[1]").map(&:text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your search is matching two different things: the `<tr>` tag nested directly within the table with id `rptBidTypes__ctl0_dgResults`, and the `<tr>` tag within the table nested *inside* that parent table. When you loop through `document[1..-1]` you're actually selecting the second `<tr>` tag rather than the first one.

To select just the *direct* child `<tr>` tag, use:

```
document = doc.search("table#rptBidTypes__ctl0_dgResults > tr")
```

Then you can get the text for the `<td>` tag with:

```
document.css('td')[0].text   #=> "S24327"
```

Comment: `css` actually gives all td's, same as `search`. `at` gives only the first one.

Comment: If you only want the first `td`, do not use `[0]`, use `at`, as @pguardiario pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the first td would be:

```
doc.at("table#rptBidTypes__ctl0_dgResults td").text
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the first, he wants all matching numbers.

Comment: Hmm, I just read the question again and he seems to ask for the first.

Comment: You're right. I assumed he wanted the first `td` in his example, and all others like it. I still think that is the case, but I may be reading too much into it.